# Something like Django from Python for JSF?

Tags: django, jsf, jsf-2, frameworks

I need a framework or library for JSF 2.0 with the same functionality as Django for Python. Is there something like this for JSF?

Comment: I don't do Django, but after glancing its key features, I gather that you're talking about ORM and transaction management? JSF is part of Java EE which in turn already provides JPA and EJB out the box for exactly those purposes. Just glue them together. To get better answers, you'd better eleborate "functionality" in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSF is a framework to build web application's interfaces, commonly in Java EE apps.

Django is a framework and tools for building simple web apps very quickly (Rapid App Development). If you're searching for that using Java, I suggest Play Framework (http://www.playframework.com/) and ROO (http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/).